# Trace32 compile .t32 file

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

I find trace32 can use some .t32 plugin to help debug OS dump.
But I can not find the source file to build it.
For example: t32\demo\arm\kernel\rtxarm\rtx.t32. 
Can anyone find me a example project?

Answer (score 1):

rtx.t32 is a binary extension to TRACE32. You can't get the sources anywhere.

However Lautebach has an development kit (EDK), which allows you to write your own extension for OS awareness. To get this EDK you have to contact Lautebach and probably sign an NDA.